# "insist on" vs "insist"

Tags: meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

[**The definition**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/insist-on-doing-sth?q=%20insist%20on) of the `insist on` phrasal verb told us that it means to keep doing something, even if it annoys other people, or people think it is not good for you.

In contrast [**the definition**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/insist) of the just `insist` verb is to say firmly or demand forcefully, especially when others disagree with or oppose what you say.

I'd like to clarify the difference between them. As far as I understood `insist on` assumes that we're already doing something, but just `insist` told us that we're just saing firmly about our intention to do something. So, in the sentences with insist:

> I don't know why you insist on talking about it.

The listener is already talking about that "it".

> I don't know why you insist to talk about it.

The listener's just saying firmly to talk about it, but not talking yet.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second sentence sounds rather awkward.

```
I don't know why you insist to talk about it.
```

A native speaker would internally understand you to mean

```
I don't know why you insist on talking about it.
```

When you say `insist on`, this should be following by a verb describing what it is the particular individual continues to do.  Though there doesn't have to be anything about annoying anyone, it could just describe a situation which is futile in the mind of the speaker.

```
I don't know why you insist on watering the flowers. (Perhaps, they're dead already).
```

But `insist` without `on` is usually going to be followed by a particular statement asserted by the one doing the insisting.

```
John insisted that the flowers be watered every day regardless of whether they're alive or not.
```

In other words, the suggestion here is that John probably said, "I want the flowers to be watered every day."

Answer (score 2):

The construction ***insist*** + infinitive is at the very least "non-standard", and many native speakers would probably say it's "ungrammatical". The standard format is ***insist on*** + present participle.

So it should be, for example *"I insist **on knowing** the truth"*, not *"I insist **to know** the truth"*. OP's idea that there might be some *semantic* difference is simply mistaken - it's just a matter of standard vs non-standard syntax.

---

Note that in constructions such as *"She insisted [that] he stayed for lunch"*, most careful speakers would use the subjunctive form *"She insisted [that] he **stay** for lunch"*. Like the infinitive, which has the same form, the subjunctive doesn't "conjugate" (for different tenses, or first/second/third person subject, etc.).